# How to change tooltip font in NetBeans IDE editor window?

Tags: netbeans, fonts, ide, tooltip

How to change `tooltip` font in NetBeans IDE editor window? Almost all fonts are correct, but for some reason tooltip text looks awful.. How to change it - where are those settings?

[image]

Comment: Could you clarify exactly what you mean by _"tooltip font"_? Are you actually asking how to make font changes to the Javadoc shown in your screenshot?

Comment: Yes, to those popup windows. You can see that font is different and it is blurry, hard to read on Eizo graphic monitor.